# Instagram /tags/\(hashtag)/media/recent endpoint not returning pagination?

Tags: ios, swift, instagram

I've been trying to get this to work for probably 6 hours now to no avail, read every stackoverflow question I could find on the topic.

I'm trying to get 100, 200, or maybe 500 photos from a single tag:

```
func hashtags(hashtag: String, nextMaxTagId: String?) -> RequestParamters {
    var params = "/tags/\(hashtag)/media/recent|access_token=\(accessToken)"
    var parameters = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
    parameters["access_token"] = accessToken

    let urlString = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/\(hashtag)/media/recent"
    if let nextMaxTagId = nextMaxTagId {
        params += "|max_tag_id=\(nextMaxTagId)"
        parameters["max_tag_id"] = nextMaxTagId
    }


    let sig = HMAC.signWithKey(C.InstagramClientSecret(), usingData: params)
    parameters["sig"] = sig
    return (urlString: urlString, parameters: parameters)
}
```

This is what I use to construct my urls and parameters for my request. My first request does not have a `nextMaxTagId`, and that request goes through, returns 20 images and a `pagination` json.

Then, when I extract the `next_max_tag_id` from the pagination block, and create a request using that parameter, I get another 20 images, but they are the same images as before and now I do not get a pagination block.

I am signing my requests correctly (as all my other API requests throughout the app go through no problem) and I am not in Sandbox mode.

Edit: I've also tried using `min_tag_id=\(nextMinTagId)`, still do not receive pagination in the next request.

Comment: Why don't you try using the `next_url` as that seems to be what Instagram suggests *"Sometimes you just can't get enough. For this reason, we've provided a convenient way to access more data in any request for sequential data. Simply call the url in the next_url parameter and we'll respond with the next set of data."* https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

Comment: I do that `error_message: Invalid signed-request: Signature does not match`

Comment: What does your request look like when you use `next_url`?

Comment: I use the 'next_url' they provide

Comment: Why do you think you get that error then? Instagram just doesn't like you? I suspect you might be formatting the request wrong.

Comment: For other requests, I could never just use their `next_url`. I had to extract the parameters of it and resign the request, then it would work

Answer (score -1):

Seems like:

1) You are using the `Instagram Developer API` with what seems like an authorized APIKey, and you mentioned you are NOT in *Sandbox*, so you're in a the `Production` environment for that [api](https://www.instagram.com/developer/).

> I'm trying to get 100, 200, or maybe 500 photos from a single tag

2) This means, combined with `returns 20 images and a pagination json`, that for 100, you need to make 5 calls minimum (*100/20 == 5*), *200 == 10*, *500 = 25*.

3) According to the [developer documentation rate limits](https://www.instagram.com/developer/limits/), the overall cap on `Production` is `5000 req/hour`, with several APIs restricted to a much smaller limit (some are `30/60 req/hour`). I'm not sure I see the exact `tag` rate limit you are hitting, but since the question mentions:

> for probably 6 hours now to no avail

it's also possible you've just been hitting the overall hourly request limit each hour.

I definitely know that this is not an answer that I enjoy giving, because it's essentially saying: **`you're stuck`**. I've actually played with the rate limits myself before, and I find them extremely limiting (pun fully intended). The only other option, albeit not as *"above board"*, is to scrape `Instagram` itself for the information you need. I say it's not as *"above board"* because if you needed info not found on a web scrape, you could theoretically scrape the mobile API through some minor reverse engineering (ie using an HTTP proxy to spoof mobile traffic systematically).

In the end, the API `Instagram` publishes is definitely very limited, and will face rate limits for the foreseeable future (unless you can get those somehow lifted in a specific partnership they somehow deem worthy, although I'm not sure how this could be approached).